# Conditional Formatting (Icons)

Tags: excel, vba, formatting, conditional-statements

I'm having a hard time adding a conditional formatting rule to a cell. This cell has a formula inside of it that returns either a "Best Case" or "Not Optimal" answer. I would like to set a conditional formatting rule so that if "Best Case" appears the cell shows a green dot and if "Not Optimal" appears a red dot shows in the cell.

My dilemma is that I don't think using texts when trying to use the Icon conditional formatting is possible.

Comment: Instead of an Icon, perhaps format the cell to a font that's rather large, and just use a period? Or find something in say, Wingdings, that looks like an Icon?

Comment: you are a genius! let me try this

Answer (score 2):

Add another column with a simple `IF` formula:

```
=IF([@TheOtherColumn]="Best Case", 1, -1)
```

Then hide that column and create a formula-based conditional format that uses that value; use a green dot for `>= 1`, a red dot for `< 0`, and you shouldn't see a yellow dot for `=0`.